# when I pressed create button application shuts down but at same time data gets stored in sql database 4 times

Tags: android, json

```
/**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post your makeHttpRequest function

Comment: post your logcat output.

Comment: Here is my logcat output

Comment: 06-22 09:46:42.803: E/WindowManager(4144): Activity com.example.sqlconnection.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d59d78 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
06-22 09:46:42.803: E/WindowManager(4144): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.sqlconnection.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d59d78 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
06-22 09:46:42.803: E/WindowManager(4144):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to request and check its working or not

```
public String request(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
{

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httpPost.setHeader("encytype", "multipart/form-data");

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Buffer Error" + "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return json;
}
```